Black Screen on Login After Installing Ubuntu 24.04 - nvidia
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my system and performed all the available updates. However, I’m encountering a frustrating issue every time I reboot. When I reach the login screen, my primary monitor goes black, and I have to log in blindly by entering my password without seeing anything.
I have a projector connected to my system, and I've discovered that if I turn on the projector, the login screen appears on it. This means the login screen is not showing on my main monitor but only on the projector if it’s powered on.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Logging in blindly (entering my password without seeing the login screen), after which my main monitor starts working normally.
Turning on the projector, logging in using the login screen displayed on the projector, and then turning the projector off.
I have also gone into the display settings and set my main monitor as the primary display while disabling the projector, but the issue persists.
Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!
I have a 3070 TI card, if may help.
Thanks in advance.
